# can't use an undefined value as a symbol perl

Tags: perl, function, file-io, hash, parameters

I'm trying to write in file some value taken from an array. But I'm having some error ''Can't use an undefined variables as a symbol reference at... line 81:

```
foreach $k (sort keys %{$value2}){
    print $value4 $k." = ".%{$value2{$k}}. $value3;



sub printit{
  $value1 = $_[0];#"ipadress" is a string
  $value2 = $_[1];#%hash2
  $value3 = $_[3];#"paquet" is a string
  $value4 = $_[4];#SOURCE is the file name

  foreach $k (sort keys %{$value2}){
    print $value4 $k." = ".%{$value2{$k}}. $value3;
    if (%{$value2{$k}} >= 2) { print $value4 "s";}
    print $value4 "\n";
  }
}

printit('ipadress', \%hash2, ' paquet'. SOURCE );
```

Could someone please indicate me what's wrong?

the things is my code is this one and it work fine. And I didn't concatanate SOURCE and it's still working fine.

```
print SOURCE "Ipadress #2\n\n";
foreach $k (sort keys %hash2){
  print SOURCE $k." = ".$hash2{$k}." paquet";
  if ($hash2{$k} >= 2) { print SOURCE "s";}
  print SOURCE "\n";
}
```

but I'm having a lot of codes that does the same thing so I wanted to create a function to be able reduce the numbers of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forgot a comma or concatenation here:

```
print $value4 $k." = ".%{$value2{$k}}. $value3;
```

Perl thinks you want to use `$value4` has a filehandle (symbol), and apparently `$value4` is undefined. The reason it is undefined is because you assign it the value of `$_[4]` but you probably want `$_[3]` (since arrays are zero-indexed.)

It looks like you intend `$value4` to be a file *name* for your output; if that's the case then you need to actually open that file to get a filehandle:

```
open my $fh, '>', $value4 or die "Could not open file $value4: $!";
...
print { $fh } $k." = ".%{$value2{$k}}. $value3;
```

So you have three things to fix:

1. Figure out why `$value4` is undefined and fix that. (When you find yourself appending numbers onto the names of scalars, chances are you probably want to use an array anyway. You could use just `@_` directly or grab the values into an `@args` array rather than a bunch of scalars.)
2. Figure out how you want to format your output string and use a filehandle, not a filename, for `print`.
3. Figure out how you want to serialize the hash referenced by `$value2{$k}`, because printing a hash in scalar context is almost certainly not what you want to do.

(Updated suggestions after I realized you're lacking a filehandle)